# Tomcat7 with MySQL does not timeout when connection to MySQL instance is broken

Tags: mysql, jsp, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I have the following setup: Tomcat 7 and MySQL 5.6 are running on separate AWS EC2 instances, JDBC driver is used. Everything works fine under nominal conditions.

But when connection between the instances gets broken (due to instance shutdown or security group blocking), my JSP is stuck in trying to get the data source, but it never throws any exception (like timeout), which I could catch in JSP:

```
ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/mydatabase");
```

After Tomcat restart, there is a lookup exception in catalina.out, but the JSPs are still stuck.

It would be great to have an exception, e.g. to detect that something is wrong with the database ec2 instance and switch to a backup on the software level. How to do it if there is no exception?

Note that this behavior is different from MySQL shutdown (ec2 instance still running), then there is a clear exception I can catch at the JSP level.

Comment: Is it possible to set the mysql to RDS with Multi-AZ, will be different or not?

Comment: Does your Resource have maxWait property set or ?autoreconnect=true added at the end of the database url? [here is an example](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

Comment: maxWait="500" and no autoreconnect